# How to select stylesheet to import based on content in XML

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to import a stylesheet based on the data source defined in the XML it is transforming.

XML1

```
<Root>
 <Source>Facility A</Source>
</Root>
```

XML2

```
<Root>
 <Source>Facility A</Source>
</Root>
```

I tried it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Root/Source/text()='Facility A'">
        <xsl:import href="Stylesheet for Facility A.xml"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="Root/Source/text()='Facility B'">
        <xsl:import href="Stylesheet for Facility B.xml"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transform just failed. Not sure how else to approach this.

Comment: *"The xsl:import element is only allowed as a top-level element."* - https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#import. Try using modes instead? Hard to advise without seeing the  entire picture.

Comment: P.S. An XSL transformation does not "just fail". If it fails, it is because of an error. If you're working in an environment that does not show you error messages, then you're working blind and you're not likely to get very far.

Comment: In XSLT 3 (and 2) I think you can use e.g. `xsl:import href="moduleA" use-when="some-static-xpath-expression"` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-static-expression) so there you can conditionally include or import modules but static expressions used in the `use-when` attribute are evaluated before and independently of any XML input document (more meant to be used with system properties or static parameters) so I don't think that will help if your aim is to include based on the input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit like saying that you want to import different modules into a Java program based on its input data: you're missing the fact that you can't read the input data until you have assembled/compiled the program.

In XSLT 3.0 you can invoke a stylesheet dynamically using the `transform()` function, but that may be more complicated than you actually need.

Another approach is to use a tool like XProc to control your workflow - or there are many other frameworks that enable you to orchestrate the execution of different stylesheets against different source documents. Camel seems to be popular at the moment, though I haven't used it, and I don't know how it compares with alternatives.